# What text editor support extraction of found results into another file?

Tags: regex, extract, textedit

Usually I have the following situation:
There is a PONO class with list of the properties.

```
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return this.userName; }
        set { if (this.userName != value) { SetDirty(); this.userName = value; } }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return this.password; }
        set { if (this.password != value) { SetDirty(); this.password = value; } }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get { return this.email; }
        set { if (this.email != value) { SetDirty(); this.email = value; } }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return this.title; }
        set { if (this.title != value) { SetDirty(); this.title = value; } }
    }
```

Is there are tool, preferably Notepad++ or VS plugin, to extract the regex output into another file?

For example: Find: "public string (.*)$" results:

```
UserName
Password
Email
Title
```

in a new file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Notepad++ use `Search`/`Find` dialog and in `Mark` tab check the `Bookmark line` checkbox - after `Mark all` you will have bookmarks on all desired lines.
[image]

The last step is `Search`/`Bookmark`/`Copy bookmarked lines` and paste them in a new file, where you can remove the `public string` part.

From v5.8.7 changelog:

- In order to reduce the confusion, new "Mark" tab for "Mark all" feature is made in Find/Replace dialog.

I guess that the `Bookmark line` checkbox and `Mark all` are placed in another tab in v5.8.6.

Comment: I don't have "Mark" tab in Find dialog. Notepad++ v5.8.6 with default plugins.

Comment: in Notepad++ v5.8.6 there is a checkbox on the Find tab for this feature, but I would recommend to update Notepad.

Comment: You can also strip out the "public string" part while within notepad++.  After Mark all, do Search/Bookmark/Remove unmarked lines.  Then go back to the Find/Replace. Click the Replace tab and (while using the original search string shown) put \1 in the replace string.  Then press replace all.

Answer (score 1):

Not a text editor solution, but

`grep "public string .+$" < file | sed "s/public string (.+)$/\1/" > out`

should work. Untested.